# Selectively ignoring tuples from a table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The problem that we are tackling with a data mining application is best described with an illustrative example.

There is a sample table `myTable`, which is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
  id        INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  colA      VARCHAR(8),
  colB      VARCHAR(12),
  revFlag   CHAR(8), -- 'REVISED' or any other value, including NULL

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Any tuple with a `revFlag` value of `REVISED` takes precedence over any other tuple with the same value for `colA`, as long as the `revFlag` value of the latter tuple is not `REVISED`.  In other words when we select rows from the table we skip all rows for which the `revFlag` value is not `REVISED` and there exists a row with the same value for `colA` for which the `revFlag` value is `REVISED`.

We populate the table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(colA, colB) VALUES ('XSR0KA3V', 'OLD-O7RAR81X'),
('4F2JG71O', 'OLD-E71BE63L'), ('MML3HN48', 'OLD-B02PFB63'),
('5H0MWVSB', 'OLD-V70XLGHT'), ('JW73ZX0J', 'OLD-KME1GXQF'),
('XZV0EY0G', 'OLD-N06BURDF'), ('9HBQZ88V', 'OLD-76HSPUAL'),
('YI5AT6G4', 'OLD-X8KAWD7Z');


INSERT INTO myTable(colA, colB, revFlag) VALUES
('XSR0KA3V', 'NEW-O7RAR81X', 'REVISED'),
('MML3HN48', 'NEW-B02PFB63', 'REVISED'),
('9HBQZ88V', 'NEW-76HSPUAL', 'REVISED'),
('YI5AT6G4', 'NEW-X8KAWD7Z', 'XYZ'),
('Z8H2B5KY', '3RINJV0K', 'REVISED');
```

Naturally `SELECT * FROM myTable` yields the following:

```
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
| id | colA     | colB         | revFlag |
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
|  1 | XSR0KA3V | OLD-O7RAR81X | NULL    |
|  2 | 4F2JG71O | OLD-E71BE63L | NULL    |
|  3 | MML3HN48 | OLD-B02PFB63 | NULL    |
|  4 | 5H0MWVSB | OLD-V70XLGHT | NULL    |
|  5 | JW73ZX0J | OLD-KME1GXQF | NULL    |
|  6 | XZV0EY0G | OLD-N06BURDF | NULL    |
|  7 | 9HBQZ88V | OLD-76HSPUAL | NULL    |
|  8 | YI5AT6G4 | OLD-X8KAWD7Z | NULL    |
|  9 | XSR0KA3V | NEW-O7RAR81X | REVISED |
| 10 | MML3HN48 | NEW-B02PFB63 | REVISED |
| 11 | 9HBQZ88V | NEW-76HSPUAL | REVISED |
| 12 | YI5AT6G4 | NEW-X8KAWD7Z | XYZ     |
| 13 | Z8H2B5KY | 3RINJV0K     | REVISED |
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
```

---

We would like to design a query that does **not** return any tuples that are **REVISED** by other tuples.  In our case the output should look like this:

```
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
| id | colA     | colB         | revFlag |
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
|  2 | 4F2JG71O | OLD-E71BE63L | NULL    |
|  4 | 5H0MWVSB | OLD-V70XLGHT | NULL    |
|  5 | JW73ZX0J | OLD-KME1GXQF | NULL    |
|  6 | XZV0EY0G | OLD-N06BURDF | NULL    |
|  8 | YI5AT6G4 | OLD-X8KAWD7Z | NULL    |
|  9 | XSR0KA3V | NEW-O7RAR81X | REVISED |
| 10 | MML3HN48 | NEW-B02PFB63 | REVISED |
| 11 | 9HBQZ88V | NEW-76HSPUAL | REVISED |
| 12 | YI5AT6G4 | NEW-X8KAWD7Z | XYZ     |
| 13 | Z8H2B5KY | 3RINJV0K     | REVISED |
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` clause to filter out all rows for which another row exists which has the same `colA` value and `revFlag = 'REVISED'`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM myTable t2
  WHERE t2.id != t1.id AND t2.colA = t1.colA AND t2.revFlag = 'REVISED'
)
```

Output:

```
id  colA        colB            revFlag
2   4F2JG71O    OLD-E71BE63L    (null)
4   5H0MWVSB    OLD-V70XLGHT    (null)
5   JW73ZX0J    OLD-KME1GXQF    (null)
6   XZV0EY0G    OLD-N06BURDF    (null)
8   YI5AT6G4    OLD-X8KAWD7Z    (null)
9   XSR0KA3V    NEW-O7RAR81X    REVISED
10  MML3HN48    NEW-B02PFB63    REVISED
11  9HBQZ88V    NEW-76HSPUAL    REVISED
12  YI5AT6G4    NEW-X8KAWD7Z    XYZ
13  Z8H2B5KY    3RINJV0K        REVISED
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=da1b080a86850cebaf4fddec2b068c35)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT stuff
  FROM somewhere x
  LEFT
  JOIN somewhere y
    ON y.thing = x.thing
   AND y.otherthing = x.otherthing
   AND y.anotherthing > x.anotherthing
   AND y.whatever = 'some value'
 WHERE y.anotherthing .... ;
```

Comment: Please, add some explaination.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IN Clause

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `colA` VARCHAR(8),
  `colB` VARCHAR(12),
  `revFlag` VARCHAR(7)
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`id`, `colA`, `colB`, `revFlag`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'XSR0KA3V', 'OLD-O7RAR81X', NULL),
  ('2', '4F2JG71O', 'OLD-E71BE63L', NULL),
  ('3', 'MML3HN48', 'OLD-B02PFB63', NULL),
  ('4', '5H0MWVSB', 'OLD-V70XLGHT', NULL),
  ('5', 'JW73ZX0J', 'OLD-KME1GXQF', NULL),
  ('6', 'XZV0EY0G', 'OLD-N06BURDF', NULL),
  ('7', '9HBQZ88V', 'OLD-76HSPUAL', NULL),
  ('8', 'YI5AT6G4', 'OLD-X8KAWD7Z', NULL),
  ('9', 'XSR0KA3V', 'NEW-O7RAR81X', 'REVISED'),
   ('18', 'XSR0KA3V', 'NEW-O7RAR81X', 'ZRNTR'),
  ('10', 'MML3HN48', 'NEW-B02PFB63', 'REVISED'),
  ('11', '9HBQZ88V', 'NEW-76HSPUAL', 'REVISED'),
  ('12', 'YI5AT6G4', 'NEW-X8KAWD7Z', 'XYZ'),
  ('13', 'Z8H2B5KY', '3RINJV0K', 'REVISED');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    `id`, `colA`, `colB`, `revFlag`
FROM
    table1 t1
WHERE
    (`colA` , IFNULL(`revFlag`,0)) IN
(SELECT 
            `colA`, `revFlag`
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            `revFlag` = 'REVISED' UNION SELECT 
            `colA`, IFNULL(MAX(`revFlag`),0)
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            `colA` NOT IN (SELECT 
                    `colA`
                FROM
                    table1
                WHERE
                    `revFlag` = 'REVISED')
        GROUP BY `colA`)
ORDER BY id;
```

| id | colA | colB | revFlag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4F2JG71O | OLD-E71BE63L |  |
| 4 | 5H0MWVSB | OLD-V70XLGHT |  |
| 5 | JW73ZX0J | OLD-KME1GXQF |  |
| 6 | XZV0EY0G | OLD-N06BURDF |  |
| 9 | XSR0KA3V | NEW-O7RAR81X | REVISED |
| 10 | MML3HN48 | NEW-B02PFB63 | REVISED |
| 11 | 9HBQZ88V | NEW-76HSPUAL | REVISED |
| 12 | YI5AT6G4 | NEW-X8KAWD7Z | XYZ |
| 13 | Z8H2B5KY | 3RINJV0K | REVISED |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aVc9AgErg7NtRnBzPDdnPt/10)

Comment: If we replace `'NULL'` with `null`, we get only 5 hits.

Comment: you are right, IN CLAUSE ignires NULL as only IS NULL can give true, so you have to repßlace the NULL values woth something that can not occur in the column